# G mail-not reviving any messages

Tags: iphone, gmail

Says there is an error and I cannot access my email- tried changing my settings from iCloud to gmail but O have not gotten an email since Sunday.

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: There's lots of details missing from here like which device (Mac, iPhone, iPad), which version of the OS, which App you're using (Mail.app, Outlook, something else).  Was it working previously?  And finally, what's the error message you mention?

Comment: See above- is my iPhone, not able to access gmail

Comment: That's a gmail error and not related to Apple per se.   The first thing to do is verify that your settings are correct. If it was working yesterday, (which it looks like it was) and stopped today, assuming you made no changes, the issue is with Google's servers.  Have you reached out to them?

Comment: I will reach out to google-thx. I added a photo of my iPhone screen message that I get

Comment: It looks like an incorrect username/password. I would just remove the account and re-add it using the `Add Account` flow.